# Select N rows grouped by foreign key

Tags: mysql, greatest-n-per-group

Suppose I have a simple table called `Articles` which has three columns `id, category_id, title`. I want to select the 3 newest rows for each category_id, thus giving me the latest articles for each category.

Kind of the equivalent of:

```
SELECT * FROM articles WHERE category_id = 1 ORDER BY id LIMIT 3
UNION
SELECT * FROM articles WHERE category_id = 2 ORDER BY id LIMIT 3
...
```

I am aware that is somewhat of a duplicate, but many examples over complicate the simple query I'm trying to build and I can't get my head around the various joins, variables etc. needed to make it work.

Just want something simple :)

Many thanks!

Comment: I think many of those answers address precisely this problem. But if you're still struggling, see http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: @Strawberry linked a duplicate of this question

Comment: Many of those answers provide a count or max. I'm not looking for an aggregate, but to get the N rows.

Comment: @John1984 the linked duplicate is exactly what you are looking for. No counts, no maxes there.

Comment: Okay, I've got this (had to take at symbols out):

set num := 0;

select *
from (select *, num := num + 1 as row_number from articles order by category_id) as x where x.row_number <= 3;

but it only returns for the first category_id. Any suggestions?

Comment: I suggest you to re-read the 2nd solution accepted answer in the duplicate topic and understand it. If you try to modify it without understanding, then you end up in a situation like this.